# TWRequest and ARC - using a value elsewhere in a project

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, twrequest

I am using ARC with TWRequest. I have successfully returned a search from twitter and created an array of the results. Here is my code...

```
NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];


            //Loop through the results
    NSMutableArray *twitterText = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (NSDictionary *tweet in results)
            {
                // Get the tweet
                NSString *twittext = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

                // Save the tweet to the twitterText array
                [twitterText addObject:twittext];
}
                NSLog(@"MY ************************TWITTERTEXT************** %@", twitterText ); </p>
```

My question is, I want to use twitterText later in the .m file under cellForRowAtIndexPath but as soon as the loop through (as above) is finished it is being released under ARC. I have set the property as strong in my .h file (as well as declaring it above just prior to the loop). Printing a log straight after the loop through as above prints the twitterText Array fine but the same Log in cellForRowAtIndex path method returns a blank. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Alan

Answer (score 0):

Alan,

You do not appear to be saving `twitterText` in any permanent ivar. As the code is written above, ARC properly deallocates `twitterText` after the log statement.

Hence, just assign `twitterText` to an ivar in your controller.

Andrew

Comment: Do you mean create another Array in my .h say, NSArray *twitterTextCopy and then say twitterText = twitterTextCopy in my viewdidload? Thanks

Comment: Alan, you need to retain `twitterText` by assigning it to a permanent location. These are typically an ivar on an instance. For example, `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *twitterText;` will do the job. Then your assignment is: `self.twitterText = twitterText;`. Andrew P.S. You appear to have some issues with the basics of Objective-C. May I respectfully suggest that you spend some time with Kolchan's or Knaster's books on Objective-C.

Comment: Hi Andrew, pls see mt first note above as I have already set @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *twitterText; but this has not actually worked. Can I just ask is self.twitterText = twitterText; declared in view did load? Thanks for your help (BTW, I have read Kolchans book, I'll try the other - thanks)

Comment: Alan, `self.twitterText = twitterText;` is how you use the @property to set the ivar `twitterText` from within the class. Without seeing your class declaration and the `@synthesize`s, I'm at a loss to see what is going on. Andrew

Comment: Ok, here goes </P> synthesize dict;
synthesize twitterText = _twitterText;</P></P>from the .h file.....</P></P> then for my properties(strong) NSDictionary *dict;
(strong) CLLocationManager *here;
 (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *twitterText;